# Post html files on Page In Confluence Via Rest API using Java

Tags: java, rest, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Does anyone has any example on how to attach html files on Page in Confluence using Confluence's RESTful API? I'm trying to write something in Java that can do this.

The api exposed by the atlassian is POST /wiki/rest/api/content/{id}/child/attachment but what is {id} here

Suppose my confluence page is
https://wiki.company.com/Results/DemoResults/Reports

I made foll request from postman:

```
POST https://wiki.company.com/rest/api/content/{id}/child/attachment
```

In params I gave `multipart/form-data:object`

In authorization I gave my creds and has chosen basic auth as type

In header I gave `X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck`

I am getting below errors:

1. {
   "statusCode": 500,
   "message": "",
   "reason": "Internal Server Error"
   }
2. Unable to verify the first certificate

Answer (score 0):

You can't POST arbitrary HTML into a Confluence page because Confluence is not storing its pages in HTML but their own storage format.

If you instead mean to upload the HTML file as an attachment you should use the attachment REST API.

You can use this endpoint :

`POST /rest/content/{id}/child/attachment`, here `id` path variable is the page id

See documentation :

https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/6.5.2/

Comment: I edited my question as i want to attach the html file. The Api they are exposing is "POST /wiki/rest/api/content/{id}/child/attachment" but what is the {id} I should give here

Comment: I tried the approach and edited my ques as getting 500 error

Comment: @YatinKanyal I think that issue is now related to your postman settings.
 https://community.postman.com/t/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate/10325/2